# How to prevent one CSS file from overriding another CSS file in React-Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am using React-Bootstrap. I have created two different components so far, Register, and Navigation. Each component has it's own CSS style sheet. I created Navigation first, then Register. Navigation looked and worked as intended. However, when I add the Register CSS, now Navigation is taking some of the styles from Register. How do I prevent this? I thought by having two separate style sheets for each component I wouldn't have to worry about them overriding each other. Is there something I need to do or add so they will remain separate from each other? My App.css file is empty besides a font-face property. And there is no other CSS. I have used Bootstrap in the past, but not React-Bootstrap, so I may be missing something simple.

```
REGISTER.CSS

@font-face {
  font-family: "Mulish-Regular";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/static/Mulish-Regular.ttf");
}

div.card-body,
.flex-column.nav,
a {
  color: #212529 !important;
}

h5.card-header,
button.btn.btn-primary {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  background-color: #2d3155;
}

button.btn-primary {
  margin: 1em;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  background: white !important;
  color: blue !important;
}

p.card-text > a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```
NAVIGATION.CSS

@font-face {
  font-family: "Mulish-Regular";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/static/Mulish-Regular.ttf");
}

.flex-column.nav,
a {
  font-family: "Mulish-Regular";
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
  background-color: #2d3155;
}

div.col-2 {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

a > span {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

a.nav-link {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

span.contactText {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

section {
  padding-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

section > p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

a.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #282a41;
}
```

Comment: Use classes instead of directly styling elements, You only select elements by their names if you have a universal style you want to apply to them, having different files doesn't work with css, CSS doesn't have scopes, last style will override the previous ones

Comment: So unique CSS names vs. the Bootstrap style names. Thank you! If you want to change to an answer I can mark it.

Comment: If you look through bootstrap files or any css frameworks, You'd see styles being applied using element names and that is to fix issues across browsers, or to simply make some of them look better, And that is the perfect use for those selectors, Specially if you have a large scale app. I don't see how an answer for this would be helpful for future readers since the answer is quite simple

Comment: I'm aware of the selectors, but that is also a problem. When I want to style an a link in one CSS file, I don't want it to change every a link in every other CSS file. I thought that was the entire point of having separate style sheets. And I'm sure I'm not the only person new to Bootstrap who has had this same issue. Everything is simple when you know it.

Comment: Exactly, You want to style one specific element, Don't use it's name but rather assign a class to it, separate files in CSS means nothing, They act as one single file, This why order is very important in CSS